# Crawling time is too long

Tags: python, web-scraping

A small program was written to crawl a target website. However, for some reason, the program does not report any errors but runs for a very long time. It is unclear where the issue may be. I suspect there is a problem in the loop, but I'm not sure where it is.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'brand', 'car_model', 'type', 'desc', 'problem', 'datetime', 'status'])

def get_info(request_url):
    headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36'
    }
    html = requests.get(request_url, headers=headers, timeout=10)
    content = html.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
    temp = soup.find('div', class_='tslb_b')
    tr_list = temp.find_all('tr')
    df_info = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'brand', 'car_model', 'type', 'desc', 'problem', 'datetime', 'status'])
    for tr in tr_list:
        tempMy = {}
        td_list = tr.find_all('td')
        if len(td_list) > 0:
            tempMy['id'], tempMy['brand'], tempMy['car_model'], tempMy['type'], tempMy['desc'], tempMy['problem'], tempMy['datetime'], tempMy['status'] = td_list[0].text, td_list[1].text, td_list[2].text, td_list[3].text, td_list[4].text, td_list[5].text, td_list[6].text, td_list[7].text
            df_info = df_info.append(tempMy, ignore_index=True)
    return df_info

request_url = input("Please enter the target URL: ")
html = requests.get(request_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')


current_page = 1
while True:
    page_url = request_url[:48] + str(current_page) + "d&cb=0&csb=0&cs=0&cm=0&ba=0&qt=0&z=0&zs=0&f=0&nt=0&fu=0&qts=0&wd=%e5%a4%87%e8%83%8e"

    page_info = get_info(page_url)

    if page_info.empty:
        break

    result = result.append(page_info, ignore_index=True)

    current_page += 1

    if current_page == 101:
        break

    if '<div class = "noCar">' in str(page_info):
        break

result.to_csv('result.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: It is not possible to say what is causing the problem.  But it could be that you have triggered the target site's "anti-webcrawling" defenses.  One tactic is to *deliberately* deliver the content to your web crawler v-e-r-y s-l-o-w-l-y.

Comment: @StephenC if he/she use selenium problem will solve?

Comment: That problem?  Possibly.  It depends how the target detects web crawling.

Comment: Try change `html = requests.get(request_url)` to `html = requests.get(request_url, headers={'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36", "Accept": "text/html"})` to "disguise" yourself as an average browser.